# how to give a image instead of bullets in ckeditor plugin?

Tags: php, css

Can anyone tell how to give an image to a bullet in ckeditor ?

I want to put the below content in ckeditor:

```
<ul class="features_li">
   <li><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>Help him</li>
   <li><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>Be careful of the danger</li>
   <li><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>The stunning</li>
</ul>
```

I want to put the content in ckeditor with image defined in the class.Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Check below example

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
ul li i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="features_li">
  <li><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>Help him</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>Be careful of the danger</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>The stunning</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: where to add this code in ckeditor ? I n ckeditr there are default bullet styles i dnt want that..i want the style for fontawesome check square as bullets

Comment: Paste `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` in your `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `fa fa-check-square-o` represents class of the font-awesome font. It permit to include images with adding some class.

See documentation here about adding these classes : 
https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

[Here a live example of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/hod8ove5/2/)

Comment: how to add the fa fa-check-square-o style into ckeditor plugin? I dnt want the default bullets in ckeditor.

Comment: You have to include this stylesheet before including the ckeditor plugin : `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` and set the `list-style` of the `li` to `none`, like in the example I've provide.

Comment: how do i get the style in the ckeditor? I cant find the style in there.

Comment: If you want that, maybe check this plugin : http://ckeditor.com/addon/fontawesome